# Android Project : Check bad CheckBox in listView

Tags: java, android

I am a French student, sorry for my mistakes.
I have to do a major project of 6 months to validate my studies. This project consists of creating an Android application.
My application consists of a listView with a custom adapter (TextView and CheckBox).
My problem is that I want to check a CheckBox that is not in the current view of my listView. For example if I want to check a checkbox at the bottom of the list and I am at the top of it (it is not visible on the screen). The checkbox check is not the right one, it ticks one randomly in the current view.

[Picture ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLOv3.png)

Here is the view code:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) selectActivity.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.station_list_item, null);
        }

        //Handle TextView and display string from your list
        TextView textViewListNomStation = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewListNomStation);
        //Log.i(tag, "nom :" +infosStationsCapteurs.cInfosStationArrayList.get(position).getNomStation() );
        textViewListNomStation.setText(infosStationsCapteurs.getcInfosStationArrayList().get(position).getNomStation() + " ID : " + infosStationsCapteurs.getcInfosStationArrayList().get(position).getIdStation());

        TextView textViewListInfosStation = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewListInfosStation);
        String formatInfos = "Lat : " + infosStationsCapteurs.getcInfosStationArrayList().get(position).getPositionGPS().getLatitude() + " Lon : " + infosStationsCapteurs.getcInfosStationArrayList().get(position).getPositionGPS().getLongitude();
        textViewListInfosStation.setText(formatInfos);

        //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
        CheckBox checkBoxStation = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxStation);
        checkBoxTab[position] =  checkBoxStation;

        checkBoxTab[position].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
//                Log.i(tag, "Bouton :" + buttonView.getId() + " Status " + isChecked);
                if (isChecked == true)
                {
                    mCheckedState[position]=true;
                    selectActivity.getTableauCapteurs().addHashSetstationChecked((cInfosStation)getItem(position));
                    selectActivity.getTableauCapteurs().createTable();
                }
                if (isChecked == false){
                    mCheckedState[position]=false;
                    selectActivity.getTableauCapteurs().deleteHashSetstationChecked((cInfosStation)getItem(position));
                    selectActivity.getTableauCapteurs().createTable();
                }
            }
        });

        checkBoxTab[position].setChecked(mCheckedState[position]);
        return view;
    }
```

Here is the code that allows me to check a checkbox in the listView

```
public void checkListStation(int id, boolean etat)
{
    //Log.i(tag,"CheckListStation : NBR STATION : " + infosStationsCapteurs.getcInfosStationArrayList().size());
    for (int i = 0;i<infosStationsCapteurs.getcInfosStationArrayList().size();i++)
    {
        //Log.i(tag, "CHECK " + infosStationsCapteurs.getcInfosStationArrayList().get(i).getNomStation() + " : "+name);
        if (infosStationsCapteurs.getcInfosStationArrayList().get(i).getIdStation()==id)
        {
            mCheckedState[i]=etat;
            if (checkBoxTab[i]!=null)
            {
                checkBoxTab[i].setChecked(etat);
                Log.i(tag, "Checkbox : " + i + " : " + checkBoxTab[i].isChecked() + "taille : " + checkBoxTab.length);
            }
        }
    }
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Here is an image that shows the problem. If I want to check the one down it will check the top one instead:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liRaT.png)

I hope I have been clear enough.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: couldn't get it "My problem is that I want to check a CheckBox that is not in the current view"

Comment: Sorry : "My problem is that I want to check a CheckBox that is not in the current view of my listView"

Comment: but how you are checking the invisible item in the list? do u have something like "Select All"? otherwise how can you check it? i mean physically it's not possible !

Comment: Physically the button is present but it is not visible but it is at the bottom of my listView for example and is therefore not visible on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the picture of what you want to do?It is not clear.
But what I think you want one listview which have multiple items and each item holds one checkbox.If it is then you can do it by using custom listview with adapter.

Comment: The image has been added. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below caode

```
public class GeneratedOrderListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    ViewHolder holder;
    Typeface tf_bold, tf_regular;
    ArrayList<GenerateOrder> arrayListgeneratOrder;

    public GeneratedOrderListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GenerateOrder> arrayListgeneratOrder) {
        mContext = context;
        this.arrayListgeneratOrder = new ArrayList<>();
        this.arrayListgeneratOrder = arrayListgeneratOrder;
        this.tf_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "opensans_semibold.ttf");
        this.tf_regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "opensans_regular.ttf");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayListgeneratOrder.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView mOrderNO;
        TextView mCustomerName;
        TextView mStatus;
        TextView mTotalAmount;

        TextView mtextOrderNO;
        TextView mtextCustomerName;
        TextView mtextStatus;
        TextView mtextTotalAmount;

        RelativeLayout relback;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.order_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.mtextStatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_t_status);
            holder.mtextOrderNO = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title_orderno);
            holder.mtextCustomerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_t_customer);
            holder.mtextTotalAmount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_t_amount);

            holder.mStatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_status);
            holder.mOrderNO = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_orderno);
            holder.mCustomerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_customer);
            holder.mTotalAmount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_amount);
            holder.relback=(RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rel_back);
           // setTypeFace();
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        try {

         holder.mStatus.setText(arrayListgeneratOrder.get(position).getOrderStatus());
        holder.mTotalAmount.setText(arrayListgeneratOrder.get(position).getAmount());
        holder.mCustomerName.setText(arrayListgeneratOrder.get(position).getCustomerName());
        holder.mOrderNO.setText(arrayListgeneratOrder.get(position).getOrderNo());

            if(position%2==0){
                     holder.relback.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f4fff5"));
                 }else{
                     holder.relback.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                 }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return view;
    }

    private void setTypeFace() {
        holder.mStatus.setTypeface(tf_regular);
        holder.mTotalAmount.setTypeface(tf_regular);
        holder.mCustomerName.setTypeface(tf_regular);
        holder.mOrderNO.setTypeface(tf_regular);

        holder.mtextStatus.setTypeface(tf_regular);
        holder.mtextOrderNO.setTypeface(tf_regular);
        holder.mtextCustomerName.setTypeface(tf_regular);
        holder.mtextTotalAmount.setTypeface(tf_regular);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model class add CheckFlag paramter and initialize to zero

```
  //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
    CheckBox checkBoxStation = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxStation);
    int check_flag=infosStationsCapteurs.getcInfosStationArrayList().get(position).getPositionGPS().getCheckFlag();
    if(check_flag==1)
    {
       checkBoxStation.setChecked(true);
    }
    else
    {
      checkBoxStation.setChecked(false);
    }
    checkBoxStation.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //Log.i(tag, "Bouton :" + buttonView.getId() + " Status " + isChecked);
            if (isChecked)
            {
                infosStationsCapteurs.getcInfosStationArrayList().get(position).getPositionGPS().setCheckFlag(1);
            }
            else{
            {
                infosStationsCapteurs.getcInfosStationArrayList().get(position).getPositionGPS().setCheckFlag(0);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I check a checkbox if I am outside the onClickListeners function? For example if I want to check 3 checkbox in my list thanks to another function

Comment: Using notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: setOnCheckedChangeListener call notifyDataSetChanged.notifyDataSetChanged refresh your list.At the time of refresh if(check_flag==1)
    {
       checkBoxStation.setChecked(true);
    }
    else
    {
      checkBoxStation.setChecked(false);
    }       is call and your checkbox is check

Comment: I allowed myself to add in the subject the code of the function that will check my checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below.

This is adater class

```
public class AttendanceAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<Student> objects;

public AttendanceAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Student> students) {
    ctx = context;
    objects = students;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.atndnc_items, parent, false);
    }
    Student s = getStudent(position);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRollno)).setText(s.rollno);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName)).setText(s.fname+" "+s.mname+" "+s.lname);
    final CheckBox cbAtnd = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chckTick);
    cbAtnd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
    cbAtnd.setTag(position);
    cbAtnd.setChecked(s.chck);
    return view;
}
Student getStudent(int position) {
    return ((Student) getItem(position));
}

public ArrayList<Student> getBox() {
    ArrayList<Student> box = new ArrayList<Student>();
    for (Student s : objects) {
        box.add(s);
    }
    return box;
}
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                 boolean isChecked) {
        getStudent((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).chck = isChecked;
    }
};}
```

Then create one object of your adater and call this method from your main activity.Here boxadater is the object of my Adapter class.

```
public void getValue(){
    for (Student s :boxAdapter.getBox()) {
        attendance.attendancelist.add(new Attendance( s.rollno,s.fname+" "+s.mname+" "+s.lname,s.chck));
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry that should be adapter